# Using typescript generics properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have an interface of the following format which describes database methods like so:

```
export default interface IRepository {
  createAndSave(data: ICreateUserDTO): Promise<User>
  findById<T>({ id }: { id: number }): Promise<T | null> // right here
  ...
}
```

As you can see from the snippet above, `findById` method is meant to take in a type and return a resolved promise of type `T` or a null value. I go-ahead to implement this in a class like so.

```
class DatabaseOps {
private ormManager: Repository<User>
...
async findById<User>({ id }: { id: number }): Promise<User | null> {
    const t = await this.ormManager.findOne({
      where: { id },
    }) 

    return t
  }
...
}
```

When I try to create the `findById` method like that, typescript gives this error of this format

```
Type 'import("../src/user/infra/typeorm/entities/User").default' is not assignable to type 'User'.
  'User' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'import("../src/audience/infra/typeorm/entities/User").default'
```

I tried to use typescript assertion to override this error like so

```
class DatabaseOps {
private ormManager: Repository<User>
...
async findById<User>({ id }: { id: number }): Promise<User | null> {
    const t = await this.ormManager.findOne({
      where: { id },
    }) 

    return t as Promise<User> // here
  }
...
}
```

but I still get the error, I am not really sure what to do from this point onward.

Here is what the User model definition looks like, I am making use of TypeORM

```
export default class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string

  @Column({
    type: 'json',
    nullable: true,
  })
  data: object

  @Column({ type: 'tinyint', default: 1 })
  status: number
  ...
}
```

What could be the cause of this and how do I rectify it? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: You've got `id: number` in the in the interface definition, but `id: string` in the User class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IRepository.findById` method's type signature doesn't mean what you think it means.

When you write `findById<T>`, it means that the method promises to work with *any* type `T`. Whoever calls the method chooses which type it is. Kind of like this:

```
const r : IRepository = ...
const x = r.findById<User>( ... )
const y = r.findById<number>( ... )
consy z = r.findById<string>( ... )
... and so on
```

And since the caller of the method can choose *any* type, it means that the implementer of the method must implement it such that it can work with *any* type. So it can't be just `User`. It has to be *any* type, whatever the caller happens to choose.

---

Now, what you probably meant to do was to create not just a repository, but a repository *of a certain thing*. To do this, the generic parameter should be on the interface, not on the method:

```
export default interface IRepository<T, DTO> {
  createAndSave(data: DTO): Promise<T>
  findById({ id }: { id: number }): Promise<T | null>
  ...
}
```

Then you can implement `IRepository<User, ICreateUserDTO>` in your class:

```
class UserRepository {
    ...

    async createAndSave(data: ICreateUserDTO): Promise<User> {
        ...
    }

    async findById({ id }: { id: number }): Promise<User | null> {
        const t = await this.ormManager.findOne({
          where: { id },
        }) 

        return t as Promise<User> // here
      }

    ...
}
```